# Why do a lot of Maven dependency versions end with SNAPSHOT?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

Is there any special meaning for snapshot in the Maven version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes

SNAPSHOT - means it's not the final version. The code is still being developed and the artifact is not released. It may have bugs.

From: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html

> **version** This element indicates the version of the artifact generated by the project. Maven goes a long way to help you with version management and you will often see the SNAPSHOT designator in a version, which indicates that a project is in a state of development. We will discuss the use of snapshots and how they work further on in this guide.

This has even long article: http://sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html see under *3.3.1.2. SNAPSHOT Versions* headline

> Why would you use this? SNAPSHOT versions are used for projects under active development. If your project depends on a software component that is under active development, you can depend on a SNAPSHOT release, and Maven will periodically attempt to download the latest snapshot from a repository when you run a build. Similarly, if the next release of your system is going to have a version "1.4", your project would have a version "1.4-SNAPSHOT" until it was formally released.

Answer (score 1):

Any project version with `SNAPSHOT` in it means that its a development build, not a release, and is usually built off of whatever's the newest commit in the repository.

This means they are *not* stable since someone could commit broken code, broken project gets built, and sometime later you update to the newest build which is broken.